Contour detection with dicom imaging
I am currently working on image segmentation on dicom files, and I will have to distinguish between areas of the image, but due to the image noise, its hard to find the big faint square.
this is the image
import pydicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from skimage.filters import threshold_multiotsu
# Use the image instead, as I dont know how to share the dicom file
#(which might also have information I wouldnt want to share)
ds = pydicom.dcmread("file.dcm")
image = ds.pixel_array

#Is this the correct way to convert to 8bit from 16bit?
image =(image / 65535 * 255).astype(np.uint8)

thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(image, classes=4)

regions = np.digitize(image, bins=thresholds)

plt.imshow(regions)
plt.show()

This is the code, I dont have contour detection included because it doesnt seem to work and detects wayyy too many contours to even draw. I am thinking of implementing some type of majority vote or blur the regions themselves(but its hard when its digitzed), but  I am not particularly familiar with image segmentation.
Also note that I mostly want to detect the big square, as the other 2 are quite easy to get even with other methods
I have worked with canny edge, thresholding, adapting thresholding and the most promising method seems to be multiotsu thresholding, which finds both small squares, but it gets messy with the the big square as even attempting gaussian blur seems to not work.

there is no big faint square. there's a little faint square, and a big obvious one.

The big square surrounds the two you mentioned
